# Can we use a formula in the “value_if_false” of the IF function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(YEAR(Q2)=2020,YEAR(Q2)=2000),MONTH(Q2),0)
```

But I want to use a formula in the value_if_false instead of a 0.

I want to use the following formula in the value_if_false field which works fine when used by itself

```
=VALUE(LEFT(Q2, SEARCH("-",Q2,1)-2))
```

So my final formula would like like:

```
=IF(OR(YEAR(Q2)=2020,YEAR(Q2)=2000),MONTH(Q2),VALUE(LEFT(Q2, SEARCH("-",Q2,1)-2)))
```

But I get the `#VALUE!` when I am under the value_if_false condition.

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some test data with which you are experiencing the issues? Ideally, one without any problems for both formulae and one where it is not working for the first (giving 0) but working for the second when used by itself.

Comment: I'm suspecting that you are working with both date and text values. In the first case, the first formula works fine if the year is 2000 or 2020, but gives 0 otherwise, but in that case, the second formula should be giving an error. If the date is a text value, then the first formula should result in an error (and not process any true or false return value, because year(*text*) is an error itself) while the second should work fine.

Comment: Formula is working with values like: 1-Jan ,3-Mar ,2-Feb, 2-Sep etc... The other values are like: 0 -1, 0 - 0, 13 - 0 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(YEAR(Q2)=2020,YEAR(Q2)=2000),MONTH(Q2)),VALUE(LEFT(Q2, SEARCH("-",Q2,1)-2)))
```

The issue was that `OR(YEAR(Q2)=2020,YEAR(Q2)=2000` is throwing the error before anything else gets evaluated, because things like `1 - 0` are not dates and cannot be converted to dates by excel automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your working example references cell A1, while the function in the if() statement refereces  cell Q2.

Does Q2 contain the “-“ you are testing for?  Because if not it will give an error, which you have to deal with - iferror() is good...

Try:

```
=IF(OR(YEAR(Q2)=2020,YEAR(Q2)=2000),MONTH(Q2),iferror(VALUE(LEFT(Q2, SEARCH("-",Q2,1)-2)),0))
```

Comment: My bad. The final formula referrs to the right Cell (Q2). Yes the "-" is used in all remaining cells. I edited my initial post